# Trying to get prev-next rows with order by-left join

Tags: mysqli, sql-order-by

The website contains images. These images can be ranked. When an image is ranked, the value can be 1,2, or 3. To save ranking I have a table `ranking_items`. The images are displayed as thumbnails. When a thumbnail is clicked, it opens the image full page with back and next buttons. when images are order by ID, back and next is fine.  but now I want my images ordered by rank AND when i open the full size image I need back and next buttons.

Heres how I query all images

```
SELECT images.id AS imageID 
FROM images
LEFT JOIN ranking_items ON images.id=ranking_items.image_id 
ORDER BY ranking_items.rank, images.id ASC
```

I create thumbnails here. the link in the thumbnail is like:

```
<a href='viewImage.php?id=$imageID'><img /></a>
```

When I load the image here is how I query it:

```
SELECT id
FROM images
WHERE id='$_GET["id"]'
```

So for my back next button I need something like:

```
SELECT images.id AS imageID
FROM  images
LEFT JOIN ranking_items ON images.id=ranking_items.image_id 
WHERE images.id < '".$imageID."'
ORDER BY ranking_items.rank_id, images.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

But this does not seem to work correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider changing your title to the original question/problem. And then either edit your post with your answer included, or actually answer here. This way it can be used by others later who may have your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the asker, this worked:

```
SELECT images.id AS imageID
FROM  images
LEFT JOIN ranking_items ON images.id=ranking_items.image_id 
WHERE ( 
          (images.id < ".$image->imageID ." AND ranking_items.rank_id='".$image->rank_id."') 
      OR 
           ranking_items.rank_id < '".$image->rank_id."'
       )
ORDER BY ranking_items.rank_id DESC,images.id  DESC LIMIT 1
```